# frequent delay of 5-10 sec in sending commands from putty redhat. Why?

Tags: firewall, redhat, linux-networking, switch, nic

When we type a command from putty, it suddenly hangs for a period of 5-10 sec or more, but the commands are sent to terminal later. So seems to be a latency which occurs frequently. But, I might be wrong too.

While troubleshooting, our observation is:
From servers with in the rack, there is no problem in connecting to our server (as they are on same switch side/ in same rack). But the issue happens when we try to connect from past the switch side. I am thinking it could be a problem at switch.

As of now, we are not in full control to physically check whether the issue is at switch.

But can anyone tell what the problem could be based on the symptoms.

And frequency of issue is random, having no fixed time interval.
And also the other servers in the rack have no issues when connected to outer network, which uses the same switch.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got suddent packet loss on the switch. Try to ping / traceroute your host and to check errors on the switch interface.

Comment: If it is packet loss, the commands I type from putty shouldn't be printed later right? So, I am guessing no packet loss? Please correct me here if I am wrong

Comment: You are wrong. It could well be packet loss. Or it might be an IP address conflict.

Comment: @symcbean But how with packet loss, our commands are still sent? and also no issues with other servers in the rack while connecting to servers past the switch. No IP address conflict too. There was ip address conflict with ipv6. Then we have disabled ipv6, as we don't use it. And rebooted the server. That doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: SSH uses TCP connection which restores lost packets

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik:  Instead of arguing, do some continuous traceroutes using tools like `mtr` and you will most likely find the issue.

Comment: Hi, yes that's right. I am seeing packet loss of 3%. Ya got it now. TCP. So what could be the issue?

Comment: It may be switch problem with switch perfomance or with patchcord. Also server performance may influent on that. You need to experiment with different states to find cause of the issue.

Comment: @Alex Thanks alex, for a quick response. Switch is not in our control, so I raised the issue to the concerned team. I have learned some good commands today. Thanks!